# Why fee basis point is used?

Tags: solidity, opensea

Can someone explain to me why to calculate royalty I often see that marketplaces instead of common percentages use fee basis points?
1% = 100 bps
I don't fully understand the advantage of this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we only have integer math operations in Solidity, the basis points notation facilitates calculations allowing for 2 decimal places of precision, during calculations before truncation. Produces less deviations due to precision errors.